# How do I generate `quote::Tokens` from both a constant value and a collection of values?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm creating a [custom derive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/procedural-macros.html) that operates on an enum. I'd like to generate code like

```
match *enum_instance {
    EnumName::VariantName1 => "dummy",
    EnumName::VariantName2 => "dummy",
    EnumName::VariantName3 => "dummy",
}
```

I've been able to get this to work using code like this:

```
let enum_name = &ast.ident;
let mut q = quote! {};

q.append_all(e.iter().map(|variant| {
    let variant_name = &variant.ident;
    quote! { #enum_name::#variant_name => "dummy", }
}));

quote! {
    impl FullName for #name {
        fn full_name(&self) -> &'static str {
            match *self {
                #q
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Requiring the temporary variable and performing the `append_all` feels very inelegant. Is there a cleaner solution?

#### Code to build the MCVE

**src/main.rs**

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate my_derive;

#[derive(FullName)]
enum Example {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
}

trait FullName {
    fn full_name(&self) -> &'static str;
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Example::One.full_name(), "dummy");
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "example"
version = "0.0.0"

[dependencies]
my-derive = { path = "my-derive" }
```

**my-derive/Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "my-derive"
version = "0.0.0"

[lib]
proc-macro = true

[dependencies]
quote = "0.3.12"
syn = "0.11.10"
```

**my-derive/src/lib.rs**

```
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate syn;
#[macro_use]
extern crate quote;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro_derive(FullName)]
pub fn has_extent_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let s = input.to_string();
    let ast = syn::parse_macro_input(&s).expect("Unable to parse input");
    let gen = impl_full_name(&ast);
    gen.parse().expect("Unable to generate")
}

fn impl_full_name(ast: &syn::MacroInput) -> quote::Tokens {
    use syn::Body;

    let name = &ast.ident;

    match ast.body {
        Body::Enum(ref e) => {
            let enum_name = &ast.ident;
            let mut q = quote! {};

            q.append_all(e.iter().map(|variant| {
                let variant_name = &variant.ident;
                quote! { #enum_name::#variant_name => "dummy", }
            }));

            quote! {
                impl FullName for #name {
                    fn full_name(&self) -> &'static str {
                        match *self {
                            #q
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        _ => {
            panic!("Only implemented for enums");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have an iterator of tokens `xs = [x1, x2, …, xN]`, you can use the **repetition** syntax `#( #xs & stuff );*` to expand it into `x1 & stuff; x2 & stuff; …; xN & stuff` inside the `quote!` macro.

Likewise, you could repeat multiple iterators in parallel, e.g. `#(#ks => #vs,)*` would become `k1 => v1, k2 => v2, …, kN => vN,`.

The repetition syntax of [`quote`](https://docs.rs/quote/0.3.15/quote/) is similar to that of [Rust's own macro system](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/macros.html#repetition), only changing the `$` to `#`. Ideally, you should be able to write:

```
Body::Enum(ref e) => {
    let enum_name = &ast.ident;
    let variant_names = e.iter().map(|variant| &variant.ident);

    quote! {
        impl FullName for #name {
            fn full_name(&self) -> &'static str {
                match *self {
                    #(#enum_name::#variant_names => "dummy",)*
//                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, currently `quote` requires every variable inside `#(…)*` be an iterator: compiling the above will cause the E0599 method-not-found error. [This is a known bug of the `quote` crate](https://github.com/dtolnay/quote/issues/7). As explained the bug report, this can be worked around by creating an iterator that repeats `enum_name` forever using [`std::iter::repeat()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.repeat.html):

```
Body::Enum(ref e) => {
    use std::iter::repeat;

    let enum_names = repeat(&ast.ident);
    //               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    //                creates the iterator [Example, Example, Example, Example, …]
    let variant_names = e.iter().map(|variant| &variant.ident);

    quote! {
        impl FullName for #name {
            fn full_name(&self) -> &'static str {
                match *self {
                    #(#enum_names::#variant_names => "dummy",)*
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would generate

```
impl FullName for Example {
    fn full_name(&self) -> &'static str {
        match *self {
            Example::One => "dummy",
            Example::Two => "dummy",
            Example::Three => "dummy",
        }
    }
}
```

in the final output.